# virtual function is not covariant with the return type of the function it overrides

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, covariance

I have the following code:

```
class ExtensionFactory {
public:
    explicit ExtensionFactory( const std::string& i_Name
                              , const std::string& i_Version
                              , const std::string& i_Author
                              , const std::string& i_Type
                              , const std::vector<std::string>& i_Keys );

    virtual ~ExtensionFactory();

};

class IOExtensionFactory : public ExtensionFactory {
public:
    explicit IOExtensionFactory( const std::string& i_Name
                                , const std::string& i_Version
                                , const std::string& i_Author
                                , const std::string& i_Type
                                , const std::vector<std::string>& i_Keys );

    virtual ~IOExtensionFactory();

    virtual IOExtension* New( const boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type& i_ConfigNode
                            , boost::mutex& i_LogMutex
                            , streamlog::severity_log& i_Log
                            , const boost::shared_ptr<boost::mutex>& i_QueueMutex
                            , const boost::shared_ptr<ExtensionQueue>& i_Queue ) = 0;

};

class FileReaderFactory : public IOExtensionFactory {
    FileReaderFactory();
public:
    explicit FileReaderFactory( const std::string& i_Name
                                   , const std::string& i_Version
                                   , const std::string& i_Author
                                   , const std::string& i_Type
                                   , const std::vector<std::string>& i_Keys );

    virtual ~FileReaderFactory(); 

    virtual IOExtension* New( const boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type& i_Config
                           , boost::mutex& i_LogMutex
                           , streamlog::severity_log& i_Log
                           , const boost::shared_ptr<boost::mutex>& i_QueueMutex
                           , const boost::shared_ptr<ExtensionQueue>& i_Queue );

};
```

When I compile this, I get a covariant error for FileReaderFactory::New. I don't have any idea why since both FileReaderFactory and IOExtensionFactory both have the same return type.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `IOExtension` names the same type in the relevant translation units? That's the only thing I can think of at the moment.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/OW72Fo) if I add enough of the missing declarations to make a test case. Are you sure this is what you're compiling?

Answer (score 0):

(Before voting that this doesn't answer his question, it certainly DOES. The answer is that his code does not have the problem he thinks it does.)

The following short, self-contained example does NOT show the error message you were getting. You'll have to provide a lot more detail.

```
class IOExtension {
};

class ExtensionFactory {
public:
    virtual ~ExtensionFactory();
};

class IOExtensionFactory : public ExtensionFactory {
public:
    virtual IOExtension* New() = 0;
};

class FileReaderFactory : public IOExtensionFactory {
    FileReaderFactory();
public:
    virtual ~FileReaderFactory();

    virtual IOExtension* New();
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```